# Math operation in a While

Tags: c++, c, while-loop

I need solve this operation in a `while` loop. The `N`,`X`, and `Z` are integers given by the user.

[image]

I tried this, but it does not show me the real results.

```
while (i <= n) {
    double r = 1, p = 1;
    p = x / n + z;
    p = p * p;
    cout << "Resultado: " <<p<< endl;
    i++;           
}
```

Comment: What is the purpose of `r`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code at least has three issues:

1. You're re-declaring and re-initializing `p` every loop iteration, losing the previous value.
2. You're setting `p` to `x/n+z` every iteration, losing the previous value.
3. Your `x/n+z` executes the division before the addition.

---

You're continuously "resetting" `p`'s value here:

```
while(i <= n)
{
    // ...
    // `p` is getting re-initialized to 1 here:
    // (losing the previous value)
    double r=1, p=1;

    // `p` is being set to `x/n+z` here:
    // (losing the previous value)
    p = x/n+z;

    p = p*p;
    // ...
}
```

Make a temporary variable instead, and move `p`'s declaration outside the loop:

```
double p = 1;
while(i <= n)
{
    // ...
    double temp = x/n+z;
    p = p * temp;
    // ...
}
```

Also, as noted by Daniel S., you require parenthesis around `n+z`:

```
double temp0 = x/n+z;
// Evaluates to (x/n)+z.

double temp1 = x/(n+z);
// Evaluates to x/(n+z). (Which is what you want.)
```

This happens because the `/` division operator has higher precedence than the `+` addition operator. Learn about [operator precedence here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence).

Comment: and dont forget the brackets around n+z.

Comment: **4.** `x` and `n` and `z` are `int` type so the division will not work - cast `x` to `double`. **5.** Should `i` be in the expression? Otherwise you're just calculating `x/(n+z)` to the power `i`. I suggest `p *= (double)x / (i + z)`

Answer (score 1):

Some C++ syntaxe mistake and a good math error

```
int i=1; // don't forget the initialization of i
double p = 1/2; // p will be your result, stored outside of the while so we keep memory
while(i<=n) // you want to loop from 1 to n included
{
    // we don't need r
    p = p * x / (n + z); // you forgot the parenthesis here, without them you are doing (x / n) + z;
}
```

So at start *p = 1/2* which is the left part of your equation
then at each loop we multiply the current value of *p* by the factor *x / (n + z)*.
As this factor doesn't change from one loop to an other you could also store it somewhere.

This should be working.

Answer (score 0):

```
double s;
double p = 1;
int n, x, z;
int i = 1;
while (i <= n)
{
    p = p*(x / (n + z));
    i++;
}
s = 1 / 2 * p;
```

Comment: please explain a bit more. Explain why the OP's code isn't working and why and how your suggestion will work